# can you specify class weights in an ensemble of models?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, ensemble-learning

i'm making an ensemble of 3 models using averaging to classify a dateset into 3 classes, i noticed that some of the models i trained excel at classifying a certain class and under-perform in the other 2 classes. so is there a way to specify weights for a specific class in a model in the ensemble, or is it only possible to specify a weight for an entire model in the ensemble like in weighted averaging? i tried that earlier and it didn't seem to help as it either lowered the effect of the highly accurate class in the model or increased the effect of the under-performing classes thus decreasing the overall ensemble accuracy.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please specify which libraries and models are you using?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what how you want to weight things, but it should most definitely be possible. However, you need to give a small example of the kind of thing that you want to do, otherwise we cannot tell what is the solution that you need.